# Scala class implementing Java interface - how to implement method taking array of generic type

Tags: scala, generics, scala-java-interop

I hava a Java interface:

```java
public interface FooJava<Element> {
  void consume(Element[] elements);
  // more methods
}
```

and I want to implement it in Scala:

```scala
// attempt 1
class BarScala[T] extends FooJava[T] {
  override def consume(elements: Array[T]): Unit = ???
}

// attempt 2
class BarScala[T <: AnyRef] extends FooJava[T] {
  override def consume(elements: Array[T]): Unit = ???
}
```

In both attempts I get the same compilation error:

```
class BarScala needs to be abstract, since method consume in trait FooJava of type (elements: Array[T with Object])Unit is not defined
(Note that Array[Element with Object] does not match Array[T]: their type parameters differ)
```

I don't own the Java class.
How can I define my Scala class to avoid this error?

I'm on Scala 2.12

Comment: Your attempt 2 would work in Scala 3. See update with some explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
class BarScala[T] extends FooJava[T] {
  override def consume(elements: Array[T with Object]): Unit = ???
}
```

or

```
class BarScala[T] extends FooJava[T] {
  override def consume(elements: Array[T with AnyRef]): Unit = ???
}
```

---

The behavior can be reproduced even purely in Scala. Although for `T <: Upper`, `T with Upper =:= T`, we can't replace `T with Upper` with just `T` in overriding method

```
trait Foo[T, F[_], Upper] {
  def consume(elements: F[T with Upper]): Unit
}

class Bar[T <: Upper, F[_], Upper] extends Foo[T, F, Upper] {
  implicitly[(T with Upper) =:= T] // compiles
  implicitly[F[T with Upper] =:= F[T]] // compiles

  override def consume(elements: F[T with Upper]): Unit = ??? // compiles

  //override def consume(elements: F[T]): Unit = ??? // doesn't compile
  // method consume overrides nothing
  // class Bar needs to be abstract. Missing implementation for member of trait Foo
}
```

Similarly,

```
trait Foo[T, F[_], Upper] {
  type X <: T with Upper
  type Y >: T with Upper
  type Z = T with Upper
  type Z1 >: T with Upper <: T with Upper
  type Z2 >: T <: T
}

class Bar[T <: Upper, F[_], Upper] extends Foo[T, F, Upper] {
  override type X <: T   // compiles
  override type Y >: T   // compiles
  //override type Z = T  // doesn't compile: incompatible type in overriding, Equivalent type required when overriding a type alias
  override type Z1 = T   // compiles
  override type Z2 = T with Upper // compiles
}
```

Probably the thing is that for `T <: Upper`, `T with Upper <: T` and `T <: T with Upper`

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#conformance

but not `T with Upper ≡ T`

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#equivalence

This behavior is changed in Scala 3 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/LHhlufv8ReqoN6w2ZL0BLQ/1